# Replacing characters in a sh script

Tags: sh

I am writing an sh script and need to replace the `.` and `-` with a `_`

Current:

```
V123_45_678_910.11_1213-1415.sh
```

Wanted:

```
V123_45_678_910_11_1213_1415.sh
```

I have used a few `mv` commands, but I am having trouble.

```
for file in /virtualun/rest/scripts/IOL_Extra/*.sh ; do mv $file ${file//V15_IOL_NVMe_01./V15_IOL_NVMe_01_} ; done
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I wanted to do this for multiple files in a directory with same naming structure.

Comment: Why not use `sed`.

Comment: I assume you mean `.` other than the one that precedes the extension?

Comment: To confirm, are you actually using `bash`, or is your attempt at using `${...//...}` raising an error?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Fail on error
set -o errexit
# Disable undefined variable reference
set -o nounset
# Enable wildcard character expansion
set +o noglob

# ================
# CONFIGURATION
# ================
# Pattern
PATTERN="/virtualun/rest/scripts/IOL_Extra/*.sh"

# ================
# LOGGER
# ================
# Fatal log message
fatal() {
  printf '[FATAL] %s\n' "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}

# Info log message
info() {
  printf '[INFO ] %s\n' "$@"
}

# ================
# MAIN
# ================
{
  # Check directory exists
  [ -d "$(dirname "$PATTERN")" ] || fatal "Directory '$PATTERN' does not exists"

  for _file in $PATTERN; do
    # Skip if not file
    [ -f "$_file" ] || continue

    info "Analyzing file '$_file'"

    # File data
    _file_dirname=$(dirname -- "$_file")
    _file_basename=$(basename -- "$_file")
    _file_name="${_file_basename%.*}"
    _file_extension=
    case $_file_basename in
      *.*) _file_extension=".${_file_basename##*.}" ;;
    esac

    # New file name
    _new_file_name=$(printf '%s\n' "$_file_name" | sed 's/[\.\-][\.\-]*/_/g')

    # Skip if equals
    [ "$_file_name" != "$_new_file_name" ] || continue

    # New file
    _new_file="$_file_dirname/${_new_file_name}${_file_extension}"

    # Rename
    info "Renaming file '$_file' to '$_new_file'"
    mv -i -- "$_file" "$_new_file"
  done
}
```

Comment: Was this written by ChatGPT? It contains a ridiculous amount of unnecessary overhead (e.g., checking for commands that any sane person would assume is available).

Comment: Of course not! If you check my other answers and my GitHub profile you will see that they are in the same form

Comment: I suggest being a little less "thorough" in your future answers. The answer to the actual question can barely be found in all this fluff.

Comment: I prefer to be verbose and use comments to explain the majority of the code. Furthermore, I prefer a full-code copy-paste solution to a minimum code that assumes too many things. Two distinct code/answer styles

Comment: I wouldn't call this an answer. We're not here to provide finished software for people.

Comment: That is your idea. We are (and think) in quite different ways.

Comment: Perhaps we can agree on one point: verbose command checking. I changed my answer :)

Comment: Not bad to be fair.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to match any of the other parts of the file name, just the characters you want to replace. To avoid turning `foo.sh` into `foo-sh`, remove the extension first, then add it back to the result of the replacement.

```
for file in /virtualun/rest/scripts/IOL_Extra/*.sh ; do
   base=${file%.sh}
   mv -i -- "$file" "${base//[-.]/_}".sh
done
```

Use the `-i` option to make sure you don't inadvertently replace one file with another when the modified names coincide.

Comment: OP may also add `-i` option to verify each renaming operation.

Comment: Probably should, since the requested rule is a many-to-one mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for f in /virtualun/rest/scripts/IOL_Extra/*.sh; do
   mv "$f" $(sed 's/[.-]/_/g' <<< "$f")
done
```

The `sed` command is replacing all characters `.-` by `_`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using sed substitute as posted by oliv.
However, if you have not familiar with regular expression, using `rename` is faster/easier to understand:

Example:

```
$ touch V123_45_678_910.11_1213-1415.sh
$ rename -va '.' '_' *sh
`V123_45_678_910.11_1213-1415.sh' -> `V123_45_678_910_11_1213-1415_sh'
$ rename -va '-' '_' *sh
`V123_45_678_910_11_1213-1415_sh' -> `V123_45_678_910_11_1213_1415_sh'
$ rename -vl '_sh' '.sh' *sh
`V123_45_678_910_11_1213_1415_sh' -> V123_45_678_910_11_1213_1415.sh'
$ ls *sh
V123_45_678_910_11_1213_1415.sh
```

Options explained:
`-v` prints the name of the file `before -> after` the operation
`-a` replaces **all** occurrences of the first argument with the second argument
`-l` replaces **the last** occurrence of the first argument with the second argument

Note that this might not be suitable depending on the other files you have in the given directory that would match `*sh` and that you do NOT want to rename.